# How to prevent the user from abusing a button?

Tags: php

i'm quite a beginner with PHP and i tried to make something to get xp when cliking the button. You just need to click and it gives xp, then it refresh the page to refresh the player's stat on screen.

```
<form method="post">
<p><input type="submit" value="Kill the mob"  name="add20xp" /></p>
</form>
 <?php

if (isset($_POST['add20xp']))
{
   $add20xp =("UPDATE users SET exp = (exp + 20)"); 
   $execadd20xp = mysqli_query($connection, $add20xp);
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1" />';
}

?>
```

The problem is that i want to prevent the user from smashing the button to prevent bugs and things like that... I tried to put sleep(1) but i can just keep spamming, wait the seconds and it works so it's not very useful.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: Doesn't sound like a very fun game...

Comment: Set a timestamp column when the user gets xp, and check if a certain amount of time has passed before allowing it to update again

Comment: You realise your SQL will update every row in the `users` table, even those of the user who is not clicking the button.

Comment: Oops you are right, thanks you Martin !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the last time the update was done in session state.  Then, only allow the button to be pressed after (last time + 2 seconds) (*Two seconds was chosen since that was the suggested interval in your original question*).

```
if (isset($_POST['add20xp'])) { 
  if (!isset($_SESSION['last_post'])) { 
     $_SESSION['last_post'] = 0;
  }

  $currtime = time(); 
  if ($currtime  > ($_SESSION['last_post'] + 2)) {
     $_SESSION['last_post'] = $currtime; 
     // ... process the post.
     $add20xp =("UPDATE users SET exp = (exp + 20)"); // fix this line
     $execadd20xp = mysqli_query($connection, $add20xp);
     echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1" />';
  }
}
```

As @Martin noted above in his comment, you want to do the update only for the user who pressed the button, which is the meaning of the comment "fix this line."

Comment: Hi, this one seems to work. It just needs another ) at the 1st if and the ";" at $_SESSION['last_post'] = 0 but it's working good, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the button for 3 seconds after the form is submitted you can use this:

```
if(sessionStogare.getItem('submitted') === true){
     document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').disabled = true;
     setTimeout(function(){
           document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').disabled = false;
           sessionStorage.removeItem("submitted");
     }, 3000);
}

document.querySelector("body").onclick = function() {
     sessionStorage.setItem("submitted", true);
};
```

We will note the submission in the sessionStorage and check, if the form has been submitted every time we load the page. Then, we will disable the button and enable it after 3 seconds.

Comment: But the problem is that the page refresh just after the user click the button to refresh the stats, i need something able to block the button after clicking it for 1 or 2 seconds

Comment: Client side validation is fine, but never on its own - always validate server side too

Comment: I understand. I modified my answer and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `php` page to this:

```
// the beginning of the page:
<?php
// start a SESSION
session_start();
// setup a $_SESSION variable
if (!isset($_SESSION["timestamp"]))
    $_SESSION["timestamp"] = 0;
//
// now put the $_POST part
if (isset($_POST['add20xp'])) {
    // check the time
    $now = time();
    if ($now - $_SESSION["timestamp"] > 2) {
         // more than 2 seconds have passed since last $_POST
         // update the time
         $_SESSION["timestamp"] = time();
         //
         $add20xp =("UPDATE users SET exp = (exp + 20)"); 
         $execadd20xp = mysqli_query($connection, $add20xp);
         //
         echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1" />';
         exit;
    } else {
       // nothing, just let the page load like it is.
    }
}
?>
```

Notice some important changes:

- the use of $_SESSION vars -> these vars are stored and can be
  retrieved at every page load -> you can use them to store the last
  time an action took place
- the $_POST part should be at the beginning
  of the page -> otherwise after you send a form, you load the page ->
  check the post -> then reload... it's not efficient
- if you put the $_POST part at the beginning, you actually don't need the page reload with the `meta` tag -> because the data are already
  updated

Comment: Can you explain what you changed? Code only answers are not that helpful